# background color not displayed in chrome

Tags: html, css

i have the following css

```
body {
background: radial-gradient(circle, rgb(148, 210, 248), rgb(58, 146, 200)) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

It makes my website background blue.

It works fine in firefox and IE but not in Chrome 13.0...
Any ideas...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding:

```
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, rgb(148, 210, 248), rgb(58, 146, 200)) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
```